# compiled gdb doesn't show debug symbol in Tui mode?

Tags: linux, compilation, gdb, tui

I compiled gdb source code from scratch on wsl2 in windows 11. And i got lots of errors about the macros and some function interface.I just solved them by hand. Finally i  got a gdb elf file,and it work well without Tui mode, but it doesn't show symbol info in Tui mode.

some pics record them. The color of tui mode also seems a little unstrange comparing to original one in wsl2.

The first three figures are compiled GDB(tui mode)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFmj0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVxGA.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSNRE.png

The last one is original GDB(wsl2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWc6D.png

Comment: Try `set style enabled off`.

Comment: It works !!, but why ? , and how can i get rid of this command...?

Comment: Your style colors are probably the same as the background color, that's why you don't see the symbols (but you should still be able to copy the text).
You could also try to set different colors, like `set style filename foreground magenta`.

Comment: `set style filename foreground magenta` do not work. i want to know how can i modify or compile gdb to get my original gdb look ?

Comment: Don't [upload screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/979052)